# USB broadcast receiver called multiple times

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I'm creating an app that connects to an Arduino via USB. The connection works fine and I can properly transmit and receive data. My problem is when connecting and disconnecting the USB.

For some reason, everytime I connect or disconnect the Arduino via USB, the `BroadcastReceives` is called from 2 to 4 times, and sometimes the Arduino just doesn't even connect at all.

My `BroadcastReceiver` implementation:

```
public static class ArduinoConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                switch(intent.getAction()) {
                    case ArduinoConfigurations.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION:
                        if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                            connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                            serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
                            if (serialPort != null) {
                                if (serialPort.open()) { //Set Serial Connection Parameters.
                                    serialPort.setBaudRate(115200);
                                    serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                                    serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                                    serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                                    serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                                    serialPort.read(new ArduinoCallback());
                                    Log.d("ARDUINO", "Arduino connected!");
                                    ((MainActivity)context).enableButtons(true);

                                } else
                                    Log.e("ARDUINO", "Port not open, not possible to connect.");
                            } else
                                Log.e("ARDUINO", "Port is null, not possible to connect.");
                        } else
                            Log.e("ARDUINO", "Permission not granted, not possible to connect.");
                        break;
                    case UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED:
                        openConnection((MainActivity)context);
                        break;
                    case UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED:
                    default:
                        closeConnection((MainActivity)context);
                        break;
                }
                ...
```

Sometimes it also throws:

```
exception in UsbManager.openDevice
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: device /dev/bus/usb/003/012 does not exist or is restricted
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1688)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
        at android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager$Stub$Proxy.openDevice(IUsbManager.java:411)
        at android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.openDevice(UsbManager.java:330)
...
```

and

```
Error on connecting Arduino: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface, boolean)' on a null object reference
```

I've read that the USB connector can be really unstable sometimes. But is it just that? Can I work around this so that the Arduino is connected and disconnected only once?